# Keyboard navigation between text fields & dropdown choices by pressing enter key not only tab key in Flutter web & desktop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-desktop

I have a big input form that is consist of textfields & dropdown choices inside table I want to navigate between them with pressing key enter

Answer (score 0):

It has been six months, but here's the solution incase someone else stumbles upon this issue:

Add the property `textInputAction: TextInputAction.next` into your `TextField()`.

This tells the TextField to jump into the next Focus when the user finishes with the current one.